# Выполнение DOS команд из C++

Tags: winapi, c++, visual-c++

Необходимо выполнить команду наподобие

```
dir C:\*.txt /b/s >> D:\1.txt
```

то есть выполнить поиск файлов по маске и сохранить результаты в файл 1.txt на диске D.

Пробовал через `system()` и `ShelExecute`, ничего не получилось. Кто-нибудь может помочь? Может быть есть другой способ, кроме выполнения DOS команды?

Важно что бы после запуска ничего не выскакивало, то есть программа тихо выполняла поиск и записывала результаты в файл.

Comment: после буквы диска и двоеточия должен быть бэкслэш: "C:\path\to\file"

Comment: Спасибо. Можете подсказать как убрать мигание консоли, что бы запускалось тихо?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используя boost (кросс-платформенно):

```
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator last;

    for (boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator d("."); d != last; ++d) {
        // TODO: Вывести *d в какой-нибудь файл
    }
}
```

Используя Windows API (FindFirstFile, FindNextFile, FindClose): [Listing the Files in a Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200(v=vs.85).aspx).